# Windows Phone 8 Missing C# Networking Classes?

Tags: c#, networking, windows-phone-8

I am trying to write a Windows Phone 8 app in C# but I'm getting lots of 'are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?' errors. It seems Windows Phone 8 is missing many C# networking classes.

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Well what classes are you trying to use?

Comment: @Arran Mainly HttpClient

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `HttpClient` class is not included by default in Windows Phone development.  It is available as a separate NuGet package though.  Add a reference to that NuGet package and you should be good to go

- [NuGet Package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Net.Http)
- [Article discussing it's exclusion from phone](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/archive/2013/02/18/portable-httpclient-for-net-framework-and-windows-phone.aspx)

Comment: So I installed the library to my project but I'm still getting the error. Do I need to 'include' the library?

Comment: @Havondale i believe you still need to add a reference to the assembly as installed by NuGet.